# Mail user agent for JMAP (Android)

Tags: email, email-client, jmap

I search a Mail User Agent which supports [JMAP](https://jmap.io/).

Required features:

- open source
- Support for Android
- Offline writing mails should be supported. As soon as I am online again mails should get sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are none. But there is one in the works called [Ltt.rs](https://ltt.rs). It's open source (Apache License). Strong offline support is one of the priorities. However *sending* emails is currently not supported at all.